# The best way of redirecting to Chrome from in-app browser on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, google-chrome, user-agent

I'm making a website which only works on the latest Chrome (above 40) and not on in-app browser such as Facebook's.

I'd like to redirect or show a kind of deeplink to Chrome if people access to the website from Facebook app or other possible apps.

What the best way to redirect people from in-app browser to Chrome?

I checked useragents
On Chrome:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.3; Nexus 5 Build/KTU84M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.109 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

On Facebook in-app browser:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.3; Nexus 5 Build/KTU84M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/27.0.0.25.15;]
```

Facebook has some "FB**" inside useragents, is it possible to show a link to open the URL in Chrome?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No it is not possible

Answer (score 1):

When your user clicks your URL he will be presented with the relevant browsers to perform the action. That means that the default browser will be presented as a choice alongside Chrome (if installed). You **cannot** force the user to use chrome let along launch it by yourself (mainly for security reasons.) You must prompt the user to select it by herself.

Comment: Thanks George. I understand the choice should be on the user. So I'd like to show some message like: "Please open this page on Chrome for the best performance", then put something like deeplink to open Chrome to make the user easier to access, otherwise the user have to copy the URL, open Chrome then paste it on the URL bar, which takes a lot of trouble. Ideally I'd like to find a way to open Chrome with just one tap. Because my app currently desn't run on Facebook in-app browser but it does on Chrome...Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot think of any way this can happen. Only on rooted devices you can perform such operations but that's a different subject. By the way, why does your app run only in Chrome and not on other browsers? Maybe we can tackle the problem there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Well, it's because the site using Krpano Video Player http://krpano.com/plugins/videoplayer/ and it's not working on in-app browser yet. It requires WebGL or maybe there are other things...